# Non-standard calculus of variations solution leads to contradiction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I've been given the calculus of variations problem of extremizing $$I=\int_a^bf(x,y,y')dx=\int_a^by\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$$ where of course $y$ is a function of $x$. I came up with what I thought was a pretty sharp solution method that got around nonlinearities in the application of the Euler-Lagrange equation, but it leads to an apparent contradiction:

Since there is no direct $x$ dependence in the integrand, the Hamiltonian/first-integral   must be constant for the extremizing $y$, i.e.
$$f-y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=c_1\Leftrightarrow y\sqrt{1+y'^2}-\frac{yy'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=c_1\Leftrightarrow y+yy'^2-yy'^2=c_1\sqrt{1+y'^2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow y^2=c_1^2(1+y'^2)\Leftrightarrow 1+y'^2= \frac{y^2}{c_1^2}.\tag{1}$$
Extremal $y$ must also satisfy the normal Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+y'^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[ \frac{yy'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} \right]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+y'^2}=\frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}+yy''\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}- \frac{y'^2}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}} \right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (1+y'^2)^2=y'^2+y'^4+yy''+yy'^2y''-yy'^2y''$$
$$\Leftrightarrow y'^4+2y'^2+1=y'^2+y'^4+yy''$$ $$\Leftrightarrow y'^2-yy''+1=0.\tag{2}$$
Substituting the first-integral expression for $1+y'^2$,
$$\frac{y^2}{c_1^2}=yy''\Leftrightarrow y''-\frac{y}{c_1^2}=0.\tag{3}$$
However, the solution to this linear ODE is not a solution to the Euler-Lagrange ODE. The only way I can see that the argument is unjustified is if $c_1=0$ and therefore $y=0$, but boundary conditions were given in the problem that this solution cannot satisfy. I've even written out proofs of the E-L equations and Hamiltonian conservation that don't appear to make any unjustified assumptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect that an extremal exists?

Comment: Because I was asked to find it as a homework problem. I suppose the problem could be ill-posed...

Comment: Choose $y$ to be a constant, then $I(y) = (b-a)y$. It can have arbitrary values.

Comment: Could you go in more detail on why you think that a contradiction exists? The integration constants of the solution $y=Ae^{cx}+Be^{-cx}$ of the last equation will be dependent on $c$, but as far as I can see, your equations are correct.

Comment: If you evaluate $y'^2-yy''+1=0$ at that $y$ with easy choices of constants (pick $e^z$), one obtains $0=1$.

Comment: Mr. copper.hat, I believe you may be confused as to the objective here. The idea of calculus of variations is to find a value of $y$ that extremizes $I$ with respect to other values of $y$. For example, the value of $y$ that extremizes the arc length functional $I=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$ can be shown to be $y=mx+b$; this is how one proves the shortest distance between points in the plane is a straight line.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the dependence of $A$ and $B$ on $c$? I'm not seeing that myself, and it makes my counterexample to the solution dubious.

Comment: Well, I worked it out in full generality still get $0=1$...

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? Can you show us precisely how you reach this contradiction?

Comment: The problem states "determine any constants of integration according to $y(a)=A$ and $y(b)=B$." I suppose it's not a hard contradiction here since possibility was left for the non-existence of constants of integration, but this professor is terse to a fault usually. If you're talking about the earlier contradiction, I don't think I can be terribly more precise than I have been already; plugging in the solution Lehmann wrote out to the ODE I wrote above in the comments yields the contradiction trivially.

Comment: For $y(x)=C_1e^{cx}+C_2e^{-cx}$, with $C_1$ and $C_2$ constants to be determined by (but not necessarily *equal to* to) the boundary conditions. Applying the boundary conditions we get $y(a)=A=C_1e^{ca}+C_2e^{-ca}$ and $y(b)=B=C_1e^{cb}+C_2e^{-cb}$. These are simultaneous equations for $C_1$ and $C_2$ which are readily solved.

Comment: @DuncanW I am familiar with calculus of variations. You need to specify the problem coimpletely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You manipulate two pretty much equivalent (if we neglect the *constant* solutions) differential equations into the third equation. The manipulation is not an equivalence, i.e. the new equation may have more solutions that the original one(s). The only thing you know is that the extremals are going to satisfy the new equation (indeed, they do as they are $\cosh$), but you won't be able to purify the solutions of the third equation to become (spurious) extremals as well.

Example: neglecting constants $y'=y$ and $y''=y'$ have the same solution $Ce^x$, however, $y''=y$ have more solutions as $e^{-x}$ is not a solution to the first two equations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer.

1. It should be stressed that the $x$-derivative of the first integral$^1$
   $$\frac{y'^2+1}{y^2}~=~ \frac{1}{c_1^2}\tag{1}$$ is equivalent to the EL equation $$y'^2+1~=~yy''.\tag{2}$$
   The constant $c_1$ is called the energy in the physics literature.
2. The solutions to the non-linear 1st-order eq. (1) are also solutions to OP's linear 2nd-order eq.
   $$  y''~=~\frac{y}{c_1^2}\tag{3}$$
   but the opposite is not necessarily the case.
3. It is straightforward to derive the full solution
   $$y(x)~=~c_1\cosh \frac{\Delta x}{c_1}, \qquad \Delta x ~=~x-x_0,\tag{4}$$
   to eq. (1) via separation of variables.
4. OP has given the Dirichlet boundary conditions$^2$
   $$ y(a)~=~A\qquad\text{and}\qquad y(b)~=~B.\tag{5}$$
   A necessary condition for eq. (5) to have solutions is apparently that $A$ and $B$ have the same (strong) sign.
5. Sufficient conditions are more cumbersome to derive. It is possible to scale the problem so that the integration region becomes $[a,b]=[0,1]$ to simplify the calculations.

--

$^1$ We assume for simplicity $c_1\neq 0$. The case $c_1= 0$ leads to the zero solution $y=0$.

$^2$ We assume $a\neq b$.